# "Failed to specialize alias template" errors for the most simple SFINAE bool condition

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm trying to implement simple condinional implementation and failing tremendously... A tried this:

```
template<class T, bool COND=0> class A
{
public:
    template< typename TT=T >
        std::enable_if_t<!COND> METHOD() const { };

    template< typename TT=T >
        std::enable_if_t<COND> METHOD() const { };
};
```

and this:

```
template<class T, bool COND=0> class A
{
public:
    template< typename TT=T, std::enable_if_t<!COND, int> = 0 >
        void METHOD() const { };

    template< typename TT=T, std::enable_if_t<COND, int> = 0 >
        void METHOD() const { };
};
```

and quite a few others... and always get "Failed to specialize alias template". What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Using newest MSVC 2022, just A<int, 0> will trigger the error.

Comment: What compiler? What C++ standard? What is the usage? Both code snippets shown compile with MSVC and clang.

Comment: A couple of example specializations would be useful.

Comment: Newest MSVC, just A<int, 0> would do that. Solution is below, but why this doesn't work, that I don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about as follows?

```
template<class T, bool COND=0> class A
{
public:
    template< bool CC=COND >
        std::enable_if_t<!CC> METHOD() const { };

    template< bool CC=COND >
        std::enable_if_t<CC> METHOD() const { };
};
```

I mean... if you want enable/disable a method of a class through `std::enable_if`, you have to check a test that depend from a template (type or value) of the method, not of the class.

So

```
std::enable_if_t<!COND>
```

doesn't works because `COND` is a template value of the class; you have to use a template value of the method, so you can add a template value `CC`, that you can default to `COND`

```
template< bool CC=COND >
```

and check `CC` instead of `COND`

```
std::enable_if_t<!CC>
```

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek - The second example in your question? For the same reason: the test is about `COND`, not `CC`.